# How to make UITableView always fit half view?

Tags: ios

In my app I need to have a `UITableView` in half of one of the views (from half view to the bottom). The problem is when I rotate the device, the tableview changes its position to always respect the height constraint.

UITableView at portrait

[image]

UITableView at landscape (when the problem occurs) 
[image]

The main idea is to shrink the tableview to always fit half of the view.

Comment: When rotate, setFrame for UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are setting the frame of your tableView in `viewDidLoad` or `init`; instead, use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in your view controller to layout your views. This is called every time the view controller's bounds changes, even after a rotate:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds), self.view.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.tableView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self.view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                          multiplier:0.5
                          constant:0]];
```